# ASP.NET Web API unsupported grant type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API for a project that I have been working on so I can easily create mobile applications. I was following a tutorial on YouTube, [ASP.NET Web API login page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq3-3ZmaMcI), and got it working with the exact code he was using. I then tried to host it online and am getting an unsupported grant type when trying to get the token, grant type is currently set as password. Anybody have any ideas on why this could be? I know that the login information is correct since it is the same I was using locally with it still connected to the live database. I've tried changing and removing the `contentType` with no luck.

UPDATE:

Here is the code that I have been having issues with. Right now I have a typical MVC razor syntax form but changed the submit button to a regular button so I can run this ajax code:

```
$('#login').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/token",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            username: $('#Email').val(),
            password: $('#Password').val(),
            grant_type: 'password'
            },

        success: function (data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
            window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
            $('#logins')[0].reset();

        }
    });
});
```

This is the only change I have done, the rest is default from a ASP.NET Web API in Visual Studio project. If needed I will update with more code. If you want to test what I am getting go [here](http://api.lock-y.com) and sign in with username: test@test.com and password: P@ssw0rd. If you go to the network inspector you should see the token pending and throw a 500 internal server error, testing this myself it doesn't say the unsupported grant type, however if you go onto something like postman and go through the same steps and point it to api.lock-y.com/token that's where it tells me that the grant type is unsupported.

UPDATE 2:
Turned on custom errors and this is the full stack trace of the error when trying to call for the token, I apologize ahead of time but I was having issues with formatting when I was pasting the stack trace so it is [in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nyy6HuyU). I did a quick google search for that error and it said to check connection strings, I compared it to the config on the working website and it looked the same. I will update again when I am at home and can find the server side code for the token.

Here are the important details of the exception:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]

UPDATE 3:
Here are my current connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=dbhere;Initial Catalog=initialCatalogHere;User Id=UserIDHere;Password=PasswordHere;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="LockyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Locky.csdl|res://*/Locky.ssdl|res://*/Locky.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=dbhere;Initial Catalog=initialCatalogHere;User Id=UserIDHere;Password=PasswordHere;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

UPDATE 4:
Here is some images of the network inspector about the error.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: since the error is occurring server-side (that's what a 500 error tells you), we'd need to see the server-side code as well, and also for you to tell us the exact exception which is thrown.

Comment: @ADyson ok, I just changed my web config to show the errors. It showed the error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found. I checked the connection strings and they look correct, I'm guessing you need the code that has to do with the token as that is what is throwing the exception?

Comment: Yes, or wherever else the stack trace of that error points to. Is it a SQLException? Post the rest of the message as well (in the question)

Comment: Ok based on that error, yeah you should double-check the connection string which is deployed on the server. Also check whether the place you're hosting from is a) whitelisted by the live database server's host and b) itself allows outgoing SQL connections. If you're saying you can connect to the same DB from your local machine, then it could be a firewall issue. Where is the database hosted?

Comment: @ADyson I'll double check the connection strings but they all appeared correct. The database is hosted on smarterasp.net, I'll post my connection strings and see if there is anything I am missing

Comment: @feare56 I really wouldn't post the full as-is string if I were you, obfuscate the URL and any credentials first.

Comment: @feare56 And did you check firewall settings? (outbound from your application's host, and inbound into your database's host?)

Comment: @ADyson Definitely don't want to forget that haha, I did not check the firewall settings. I don't know of a way to view that on smarterasp. On the non-api version of my website the connection strings are identical and have no issue accessing the database from it, I'm not sure if web api's are a little different as I am pretty new to api development

Comment: Nothing to do with API / not API, it's to do with whether a SQL connection on port 1433 can be made from your application's location to your database's location. The SQL host may well have a whitelist of IPs which are allowed to connect (did you have to set that up in order to connect from your development machine?), and the web host may well disable outbound SQL connections. If you're not sure, ask the support people for the respective hosting services.

Comment: @ADyson I haven't had to do that on my dev machine, I've been using the exact same connection string for the website and the program that goes along with it. I was going to make an api to make it easier with mobile app development. I'll be able to try more things when I get home but I used the exact same connection string on my dev machine and was able to get a token back and continue to use the website as normal. I should also mention the live version is hosted on smarterasp as well so shouldn't have any issues there

Comment: If you or anyone wants to test for themselves go to lock-y.com and api.lock-y.com, first one will work and the api will not, same connection strings. If anyone does try I have login info in original post under the first update. If successful it should go to Home/Create since nothing is on that account

Comment: Ah you didn't make that clear. If they're hosted within the same account perhaps you just need to use localhost instead of the hostname. I don't know. Or maybe because you're connecting from a subdomain it's blocked. hard to know. Maybe check with the hosting company, they may have some documentation / samples. The fact you used a web API should make no difference at all on its own - this exception has nothing to do with the HTTP connection between the browser and the API, and everything to do with the TCP connection between the API and the database.

Comment: @ADyson But then wouldn't the non-api version of the site not work? I'll look into the hosting company when I get home, just seems strange that I'm having connection issues. Is there any other place that has connection strings in a web api project besides the web.config? Specifically for the token as that's where the error is thrown? Another detail I forgot about is before I added authorization to the api/devices I could get all the devices and have full crud with the api on the live site

Comment: "Is there any other place that has connection strings in a web api project besides the web.config?" In any type of project you can put a connection string wherever you like (e.g. even hard-coded into a C# variable if so desired), but it's normal to put it in web.config.

Comment: It's hard to see how you could have had it working fully and then just added authorisation and this one single method fails to connect to the DB. So either a) you changed something else as well (even by accident) or b) this method connects to the DB a different way or c) you're somehow looking at the wrong exception message.

Comment: @ADyson if I didn't add the authorization I'm almost certain it would still work, it's just that now I need a token to access that information and after I try and submit and get the token, the token request in the network inspector is showing that 500 error. I'll add a screenshot in the post to further clarify what I am having issues with

Comment: it would be more beneficial to show the code on the server which handles the request for the token

Comment: Ok, I will post that later tonight when I can look for that bit of code

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten it to work! It turns out it was my connection strings, must have copied my connection strings from the last hosting account I had. Thank you all for your help!